# Merging tags metrics measurements and code-metrics?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics), [measurement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement), [code-metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-metrics) seem to overlap very much:

- [metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics) is the most used with 77 questions to date. I propose to keep this one.
- [measurement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) has 9 questions which are also [metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics) questions, 4 quality metrics (including performance) questions, 5 productivity or workload related metrics questions, 2 algorithmic metrics questions.  2 questions are unrelated to measurements and are about unit of measures in the more general sense.
- [code-metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-metrics) has 4 questions which are also [metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics), 9 questions which are genuine code metrics,  3 complexity questions, and 3 productivity related metrics questions.

So, it appears that in practice, it's very difficult to keep them apart.

Furthermore, tt appears the subjects are so tightly interrelated that it will be difficult to assign questions more accurately.  For example:

- "measurements" and "metrics" are tightly interlinked, and often it's about both the metric and how to measure.
- productivity metrics can be related to code and size metrics per amount of time, but also about estimating metrics per amount of time (e.g.story points burndown) and even quality metrics (defects metrics are related to additional work)
- quality metrics can be related to defects, to other observable quality attributes of the running software, but also to the internal structure of the software  (dependencies, coupling, etcs...).

Would you agree to merge them ?  And if yes, could someone define synonyms in order to avoid further discrepancies ?